# How to get Yahoo Finance Historical Closing Price from URL

Tags: yahoo-finance

I need to fetch the closing price of given stock at specified dates from Yahoo Finance API. However, there does not seem to be any good documentation on how to achieve this.

Comment: yahoo finance API no longer provides this data

Comment: I dont think that API exists anymore, https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/m-p/250503#U250503 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages:

- pandas_datareader
- fix_yahoo_finance

Example script:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

yf.pdr_override()
print(web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start="2018-01-01", end="2018-01-07"))
```